# Export JAR file not working

Tags: java, jar

I've been working on a project in eclipse for a while and now I need to export it as a JAR file so that I can transfer it to other computers and share it with the people I am working with.

Having never exported anything as a jar before, I googled how to export a jar file and followed the instructions and finally exported. However, whenever I do this (I have tried exporting my project multiple times before asking a question here), I always get the message that my classes have been exported with compile warnings.

Additionally, when I try to launch the jar file, I get a message that it cannot be launched. I have tried everything I can think of to get the jar to export and I have looked at a lot of different questions looking for a solution to my problem, but I can't seem to find one. I'm at my wits end, and if anyone could give me a way to fix this problem, I would be very grateful.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How did you create the jar?

Comment: As [eohomegrownapps](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3575587/eohomegrownapps) mentioned: Look at the compile warnings and try to fix them. Please could you post them?

Comment: I'm not sure what the compile warnings are. The only errors in my code are yellow highlighted unused parameters, which surely couldn't be causing my problem, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy your jar somewhere else on your computer and check if it is working fine.

It might  be because of depending classes. To overcome this, add your additional jars when you compile your jar using eclipse to have a little big jar: File -> Export -> Java -> Runnable JAR File -> (then choose) Package required library.... option.

Also, when you deliver your jar, you may ask your client to run CMD (for windows) and then check "Java -jar {your jar file name}" to see what is going on there on their computer.

Comment: I'm confused. What type of thing should I choose for the Launch Configuration?

Comment: Launch configuration: your main class (I think)